# iCloud shows storage being used but files are not visible

Tags: ipad, icloud, books

iPad 2017 (currently running iPadOS 13)

I primarily use my iPad for reading and have about 200 documents in Books (PDFs and ePubs; none downloaded through Apple.)

When I go to the iCloud settings in my iPad, I see 2.1 of 5 GB being taken up by documents (and those alone). Only Safari, Books and Acrobat Reader are enabled under 'Apps using iCloud', along with iCloud Drive.

On icloud.com, it's  similar: 2.06 GB used up by documents, but when I go to iCloud Drive it's empty except for couple of documents.

Every time I download a new document or rename it, I see a little cloud symbol momentarily pop-up next to the title. I assumed that the documents were being uploaded to iCloud drive, but I'm not able to find them.

Could someone please help me figure out why cloud storage is being used while the documents are missing?

Comment: Documents in the settings panel refers to all apps. Can you expand the storage usage and see what entries account for the usage?

Comment: Apple Books: 2 GB, iCloud Drive 9.9 MB; Apple Books: 0.4 KB (yes, again!); Backups 0 KB; Siri - (nothing). Weird seeing Siri there, as I have it turned off.

Comment: I've added an Answer since I believe I understand your situation now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PDFs and books stored in the Books app are taking up your 2GB of storage. You can disable these documents uploading to iCloud in Settings > Books. Disable the switch labeled "iCloud Drive."

When you download a document in Safari, it goes to the location specified in Safari settings. You can open Settings > Safari > Downloads and see what it says. On my phone, it says "On My iPhone / Downloads." To view these documents, open "Files" and click Browse tab to navigate to the location mentioned above. For me, that means clicking "On My iPhone" under "Locations" in the Browse tab, then clicking the Downloads folder.

Comment: When I download a PDF, I open it in Safari and then do a 'Copy to Books' from the "upload" button. And when it's ePub, I download it to Safari, open it via Books and then save a copy there. However, I mostly have PDFs, and can only see the handful of ePubs in the download folder in Files.

Also, I don't want to disable the upload to Drive -- I actually need it, in fact. It's just that I'm not able to locate them in iCloud.

Comment: They're in the Books app. There is no other interface to locate these, just through the app.

Comment: Hm... sorry if this makes me sound dense, but then why is iCloud taking up all that space if I can't access the documents from Drive?

Comment: @navneethc It's still syncing the books between devices within the books app

Comment: That's not good design, if I can't see them. :( I'm planning to upgrade my iPad and was wondering if there's a way to check if all my documents were secure in the cloud. (I don't use any other iDevices.)

Comment: @navneethc Unless absolutely necessary, you should be purchasing a new iPad before trading in your current one. Apple's trade in platform can credit your original purchase, or you can sell it yourself. There's no requirement to trade it in beforehand.

Comment: I won't be trading it beforehand per se, but I will have to hand it over at an Apple-authorised retailer when I buy a new one from them. The process seems to be simpler than selling it on my own. (Apple Trade In credit is only applicable for iPhones where I live.) Based on your input, I will clarify with them about data backups and such. Thank you very much for your taking your time to explain all this. I will mark this as question as solved.

Comment: @navneethc Gotcha - happy to help, and hopefully everything transfers well. Last thing of note, a proper iCloud Backup should ensure the data is somewhere. You may need to purse additional space for this though.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm looking into either an iCloud back-up or a manual one to my laptop with iTunes (and thence to another cloud service).